# Why isn't column alias working in H2 CTE?

Tags: sql, h2

I'm porting a query that works fine in Postgres into H2 but am having problems with one of the CTEs.

I've simplified it down to the following, which should be reproducible using the built-in H2 tables.

```
WITH CTE_TABLE AS (
   SELECT catalog_name AS ALIASED_COLUMN 
   FROM information_schema.catalogs
)

SELECT ALIASED_COLUMN FROM CTE_TABLE
```

The error I get is `Column "ALIASED_COLUMN" not found`

When I do a `SELECT *` instead on the outer query, it's showing the column name as `CATALOG_NAME`. But if I just run the query in the CTE on it's own, I get a column called `ALIASED_COLUMN`.

I can't see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing this H2 v1.4.196. It appears to be working in 1.4.197.